# Magento 2 SOAP api not working

Tags: magento-2.1, soap, soap-api-v2

I am not able to access product details using SOAP API while i call api url i am getting Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://127.0.0.1/test_magento_2/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductTypeListV1' : failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1/test_magento_2/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductTypeListV1" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test_magento_2/api.php:59 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/test_magento_2/api.php(59): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://127.0.0....', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test_magento_2/api.php on line 59
```

I am using magento 2.1.5 
and I have also set necessary setting in php.ini files for soap like
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
i am facing this issue in my local system and in live server.

My code for call SOAP API:

```
$token = 'kxij7mg931mxc3h2hy7dyvxm9m3fy4k4';
$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];
$wsdlUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/test_magento_2/soap/default?wsdl&services=catalogProductTypeListV1';
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context]);
$soapResponse = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
var_dump($soapResponse);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting out the **foreach** in `vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Authorization.php` ( line 36 to 40 )

Should look like this:

```
public function isAllowed($aclResources)
{
    //foreach ($aclResources as $resource) {
    //    if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed($resource)) {
    //        return false;
    //    }
    //}
    return true;
}
```

I had the same problem, this fixed it.

Comment: I think we should allow resource from the integration section of API resources. That would do the magic!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you have a error or a missed configuration on permissions,

to check the WSDL comment this line in "Magento\Webapi\Model\AbstractSchemaGenerator":

```
protected function getAllowedServicesMetadata($requestedServices)
{
    $allowedServicesMetadata = [];
    foreach ($requestedServices as $serviceName) {
        $serviceMetadata = $this->getServiceMetadata($serviceName);
        foreach ($serviceMetadata[ServiceMetadata::KEY_SERVICE_METHODS] as $methodName => $methodData) {
            if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed($methodData[ServiceMetadata::KEY_ACL_RESOURCES])) { 
//Comment

            //    unset($serviceMetadata[ServiceMetadata::KEY_SERVICE_METHODS][$methodName]);
            }
        }
        if (!empty($serviceMetadata[ServiceMetadata::KEY_SERVICE_METHODS])) {
            $this->removeRestrictedRoutes($serviceMetadata);
            $allowedServicesMetadata[$serviceName] = $serviceMetadata;
        }
    }
    return $allowedServicesMetadata;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the `SOAP Web Services` on my local host and it was working fine. The reason why the `Magento 2` was not able to give a response to the request was because it was not able to verify `SSL Certificates` enabled on the site.

The way I resolved it was to allow self signed `SSL verification`:

```
$opts = [
    'http' =>
     [
         'header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token
        ],
'ssl' => [
    'allow_self_signed' => true , 
    'verify_peer' => false, 
    'verify_peer_name' => false]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```

I hope it helps. ;)